# How to get the property in a table dynamically with other table's property?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a product table and a promote table. and I want to get the Price of the Product mix of the  Product and the promote table.

In the Product table:

```
Id       Name         Price         Detail
1    ProductName1      10            dddd
2    ProductName2      12            ssss
3    ProductName3      14             1
```

In the Promote table:

```
Id       ProductId          Price           StartDate      EndDate
1            1                20             2020/06/06     2020/07/07
```

I want to get the Price of the Product. and will get the Promote Table if there is a price that is for the Product.

```
var product =_context.Products.FindAsync(1);
```

`product.Price` is the right value.
for example. If I want to get the product with the Id 1 and then I get the promote of the ProductId 1 there did exist the Price of 20 then the Price I get is 20.
If I want to get Product 2 there is no a Price in the promotes then the price I get is 12.

I will create the class:

```
public class Product{
    private decimal _price{get;set;}
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public decimal Price{
          get{
             var promote = await _context.Promotes.Where(p=>p.ProductId==Id).ToListAsync();
             if(promote.Count>0){
                  return promote[0].Price;
             }
             return _price;
          }
          set{_price=value;}
```

But it not work.
How to do it?

Comment: So, you want to _either_ return the product price, or the promote price? But not both simultaneously?

Comment: By any chance is it failing because of the use of `await` in the getter? It seems strange to have properties that are supposed to be async. Not sure if it's allowed or not, but it seems very strange.

Comment: @Dennis1679 thank you for your answer. yes but not both price.If there is promote price then return the promote price otherwise return the product price.

Comment: @Dennis1679 I want to do with the promote price .as you know a product may have some promotes and will have a price in some date. how do you do with this? get the list of the promote tables? before the order is created? I think it may be a little complex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use the [EF Core Include](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#eager-loading) method to *include* the Promote inside of the Product model, then you just need to query for this data once.

```cs
var productList = 
    _context.Products.Where(product => product.Id == id)
                         .Include(product => product.Promote)
                     .ToList();
```

Now `product.Price` will return the `promote.Price` if it isn't null, otherwise it returns the `product._price`.

```cs
public class Product
{
    private decimal _price;

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public decimal Price
    {
        get => Promote?.Price ?? _price;
        set => _price = value;
    }

    public Promote Promote { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.but I do not want to use Include. Can I use await in the getter?

Comment: I take it back.When using asynchronous code the way you want to do, there are so many anti-patterns all in one place, it scares me. In my opinion, you should reconsider the Include and save you countless hours of bug-fixing and creating workarounds to make this work.